# I cant position the phone icon in footer by hamburger

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, positioning

I have a basic bootstrap website. When the navbar switches to the hamburger icon on smaller screens, I would like to add a Phone Icon (linking to a phone number) so mobile users can easily call. I tried adding a phone icon to the left of the hamburger, by adding the code just before the .navbar-toggle button, but I can't figure out how to make it responsive like to hamburger icon. I can position it, but that doesn't keep it responsive.

Here is my current code. I tried to get it working with just the phone icon.

I tried to make another ul(I will put media queries later) and that didn't seem to work.

The end result should look something like this.
[image]

```css
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# General
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

body {
  background: #fff;
  color: #666666;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: #b71c1c;
}

a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
  color: #2dca98;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Prelaoder */
#preloader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  background: #fff url("https://odin.rs/img/logo.gif") no-repeat center center;
}

/* Back to top button */
.back-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 12px 9px 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  transition: background 0.5s;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .back-to-top {
    bottom: 15px;
  }
}

.back-to-top:focus {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
}

.back-to-top:hover {
  background: #b71c1c;
  color: #fff;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Header
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
#header {
  padding: 30px 0;
  height: 92px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  z-index: 997;
}

#header #logo {
  float: left;
}
#logo > a > img:hover{
  transform:scale(1.1) ;


}
#header #logo h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#header #logo h1 a, #header #logo h1 a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

#header #logo img {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #header #logo h1 {
    font-size: 26px;
  }
  #header #logo img {
    max-height: 40px;
  }
}

#header.header-fixed {
  background: rgba(52, 59, 64, 0.9);
  padding: 20px 0;
  height: 72px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Hero Section
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
#hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(../img/hero-bg.jpg) top center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  #hero {
    background-attachment: fixed;
  }
}

#hero:before {
  content: "";
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#hero .hero-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

#hero h1 {
  margin: 30px 0 10px 0;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 56px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #hero h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 36px;
  }
}

#hero h2 {
  color: #eee;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #hero h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
}

#hero .btn-get-started {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 28px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
}

#hero .btn-get-started:hover {
  background: #b71c1c;
  border: 2px solid #b71c1c;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Navigation Menu
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Nav Menu Essentials */
.nav-menu, .nav-menu * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

.nav-menu li {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-menu > li {
  float: left;
}

.nav-menu li:hover > ul,
.nav-menu li.sfHover > ul {
  display: block;
}

.nav-menu ul ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

.nav-menu ul li {
  min-width: 180px;
}

/* Nav Menu Arrows */
.sf-arrows .sf-with-ul {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.sf-arrows .sf-with-ul:after {
  content: "\f107";
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.sf-arrows ul .sf-with-ul:after {
  content: "\f105";
}

/* Nav Meu Container */
#nav-menu-container {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #nav-menu-container {
    display: none;
  }
}

/* Nav Meu Styling */
.nav-menu a {
  padding: 0 8px 10px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  outline: none;
}

.nav-menu > li {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.nav-menu > li > a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #b71c1c;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.nav-menu a:hover:before, .nav-menu li:hover > a:before, .nav-menu .menu-active > a:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.nav-menu ul {
  margin: 4px 0 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.nav-menu ul li {
  background: #fff;
}

.nav-menu ul li:first-child {
  border-top: 0;
}

.nav-menu ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333;
  transition: 0.3s;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: none;
}

.nav-menu ul li a:hover {
  background: #b71c1c;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-menu ul ul {
  margin: 0;
}

/* Mobile Nav Toggle */
#mobile-nav-toggle {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: none;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#mobile-nav-toggle i {
  color: #fff;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #mobile-nav-toggle {
    display: inline;
  }
}

/* Mobile Nav Styling */
#mobile-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 18px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 998;
  background: rgba(52, 59, 64, 0.9);
  left: -260px;
  width: 260px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

#mobile-nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#mobile-nav ul li {
  position: relative;
}

#mobile-nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 22px 10px 15px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  outline: none;
}

#mobile-nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

#mobile-nav ul li li {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

#mobile-nav ul .menu-has-children i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}

#mobile-nav ul .menu-has-children i.fa-chevron-up {
  color: #b71c1c;
}

#mobile-nav ul .menu-item-active {
  color: #b71c1c;
}

#mobile-body-overly {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 997;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(52, 59, 64, 0.9);
  display: none;
}

/* Mobile Nav body classes */
body.mobile-nav-active {
  overflow: hidden;
}

body.mobile-nav-active #mobile-nav {
  left: 0;
}

body.mobile-nav-active #mobile-nav-toggle {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
    <div class="container">

      <div id="logo" class="pull-left">
        <a href="#hero"><img src="img/logo.png" width="120" alt="" title="" /></img></a>
      </div>

      <nav id="nav-menu-container">
        <ul class="nav-menu">
           <li><a href="tel:+381 64 169 0373">
            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a></li>
          <li class="menu-active"><a href="#hero">Početna</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">O nama</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services">Usluge</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Kontakt</a></li>
          <li><a href="en.html"><img src="img/en1.png"></a></li>

        </ul>
        <ul class="nav-menu-container nav-menu visible-xs">
        <li class="pull-right"><a href="+381 64 169 0373"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
        </a></li>
      </ul>
      </nav><!-- #nav-menu-container -->
    </div>
  </header><!-- #header -->
```

Comment: can you create a jsffidle?

Comment: Ok, just did...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sogpz786/1/

Comment: i cant see nothing from your example its not working  no hamburger  and mobile example not showing

Comment: but lets give it a try  add the icon  in same ul of the menu and give it display:flex; and if not plz make a full working example so we can help you